# Using probability density function plots in R to assess threshold avoidance

Tags: r, probability-density

Although there are probably better ways of doing this, I am looking to use Probability Density Function plots in R to somehow show and estimate the probability of avoiding certain thresholds of extreme precipitation (in mm/day) that are associated with greenhouse gas emissions. For example, I would like to use these plots (unless there is a better method?) to determine the probability of avoiding a precipitation value of 200 mm/day, as well as estimating the remaining amount of emissions left before reaching the emission value associated with that 200 mm/day precipitation event.

In a data table, I have the variable for the greenhouse gas emissions (which is to be plotted on the x-axis of the Probability Density Function plot), as well as data for extreme precipitation. However, I am not sure if there is a way to incorporate two variables on a probability density function? Here is what I have:

```
Newestplot <- ggplot() + geom_density(data=GEV, mapping = aes(x = em45), color = 
"midnightblue", size = 3) + xlab("Global One-day max (mm/day)") + ggtitle("RCP 4.5") + 
xlim(250, 550) + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=54)) + 
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=54)) + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=54)) + 
theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Some sample data here:

```
Emissions (Terratons of Carbon)   Precipitation (mm/day)
0.05                              170
0.06                              171
0.07                              172
0.08                              173
```

Sample image

[image: This image shows an example precipitation threshold at a particular emission level. The idea would be to estimate the probability of avoiding that threshold, or any other hypothetical threshold]

This successfully produces a density function of the emission values, but I am thinking that these plots only show the densities associated with different emissions levels. This is as opposed to considering both emissions and associated extreme precipitation values to determine/estimate the probabilities of avoiding emission levels tied to extreme precipitation thresholds of interest (which is the idea behind my analysis)?

Thank you for your time, and any feedback or suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: If this is about the code to visualize it, can you add sample data? If it's about how to analyze bivariate distributions, it might also be applicable (perhaps more-so) on [stats.se].

Comment: @r2evans - The idea is to visualize the code better. I included sample data to give a better idea of the structure of the dataset, as well as a sample image of what the plot could potentially look like.